# How to keep back the floating action button behind the textview

Tags: android, floating-action-button

i have an floating action button.

[image]

when i pressed button, the button comes above like this..

[image]

but i dont want this.

i want to keep back the floating action button.

My codes :

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/box_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="#ffc800"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_box"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:text="0"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_text"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

how can keep back the floatin action button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the property of FAB, if you want these design use a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_box" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```